# Download Ubuntu Mobile To HTC One?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, htc

So I am in love with Ubutnu, but haven't really looked into the mobile platform until just recently. I think it looks beautiful, and am excited to have the power of a fully functional computer in my hand.

I have also heard of some devices being able to dual boot into both Android and the Ubuntu mobile OS. Is this the case with all Android devices, or are there only a few capable of this? If only select devices can do it, what causes them to be able to do so? (For example, do they need access to a sort of "phone bios"?)

I am looking to buy the HTC One here in a month or so when my version contract renews, but was interested if it could also run Ubuntu Mobile.

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

status of Ubuntu Phone for HTC One, with instruction, is available from here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/M7

Note, that this is community support, and by looking at it, no much change seems to have happened during the last 6 month.